# OnePage Checkout translation

Tags: magento2

I'm using the default one page checkout of Magento 2.
I've translate everything except "place order" button !

I tried through i18n files of module and theme but nothing change !

I think it's related to Java or something like that, because place order button still hidden until you choose one of payment methods.

Could you please advise how I can solve this issue ?

Best regards.

Comment: First check "placed order" text is being there in js-translation.json file in your browser network tab. if not then please clear Translation cache and page cache then reload the checkout page with private window.

Comment: Hi @Vino .. Unfortunately nothing changed.

Comment: Dear friends, after many checking finally it's solved.
It was browser cache issue.

Comment: 7ill - Fine. Thanks for the update. if it is browser cache then it should be resolve by using private window.

Answer (score 0):

Please try in following way :

Inside your custom theme folder, Create an **i18n** folder

```
app/design/frontend/CustomVendor/CustomTheme/i18n
```

After then create the **en_US.csv** using the below command

```
php bin/magento i18n:collect-phrases -o "/app/design/frontend/CustomVendor/CustomTheme/i18n/en_US.csv" /app/design/frontend
```

and then add the below text

```
"Place Order","Your Custom Text Here"
```

Then run the below commands

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Thanks